# There is another way to do this? XSLT nested for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

my question is about how to do this for n dates and 'fechas'(another template not allowed). I do it the hard way, I'm very new on the 'for-each' function. Thanks!

**input xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transformer.xsl"?>
<dc>
   <date>11</date>
   <date>20</date>
   <status>Available</status>
   <status>Collected</status>
</dc>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="/dc/status">
    <date>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:attribute name="fechas">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="/dc/date">
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>    
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position()=2">
            <xsl:attribute name="fechas">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="/dc/date">
                <xsl:if test="position()=2">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>    
        </xsl:if>
    </date>
</xsl:for-each>
```

And this is my output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <date fechas="Available">11</date>
 <date fechas="Collected">20</date>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="dc/date">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="../status[$pos]">
                <xsl:attribute name="fechas">
                    <xsl:value-of select="../status[$pos]"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

See Transformation at http://xsltransform.net/pNvs5w4

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the 'copy' function. Something else to learn. :)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <date fechas="{dc/status[1]}>
    <xsl:value-of select="dc/date[1]"/>
  </date>
  <date fechas="{dc/status[2]}>
    <xsl:value-of select="dc/date[2]"/>
  </date>
</xsl:template>
```